# Need to generate an access key specific to an device id (android_id for android apps)

Tags: php, android, license-key

I need to generate an access key specific to a device id (android_id for an android device). The key would only unlock the application on that device. How do I go about generating this access key on my server side? Any php code/library available?  What needs to be done on the app side ( android ) to read/process/decrypt the access key and unlock the application on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with with using a randomly generated key, you can create it on the server and send it to the device or give it to the user to enter. Alternatively, you could have it generated on the device and send it to the server to be stored. Then store the key and id it is related to in the database in the shared preferences. When the user opens the app, pull the id and key from the preferences, send them to the server and have it verify they are correct.

**Update**

For a non-random code, you can use `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`, as explained [in the Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html). You'll want to be careful with it though, as outlined in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/536986).

Comment: Cameron, more than random, I am looking for a "device dependent" access key. I want to generate this key on the server (based on the user's device id -eg: 22a000004228cg45 ), and give it to the user. User enters the key manually, and the app is activated for that device. The same key should not work on other devices.